# Elimination of $x,y,z$ to find relation between $a,b,c$ from some simultaneous equations

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials, systems-of-equations, symmetric-polynomials

Eliminate $x,y,z$ $;$

$ax+by+cz=ax^2+by^2+cz^2=xy+yz+xz=0 ;$

This question is from an olympiad book which does not provide solutions but answers to only selected questions this question is one of them

I have been trying this for long but didn't end up solving it

My approaches were as follows:-
substituting $x$ from the last equation in the 1st and 2nd equation, then I tried to solve those two equations and the result I derived was

$a=(y+z)^3/(yz)^2 ;$

$b=(x+z)^3/(xz)^2 ;$

$c=(x+y)^3/(xy)^2 ;$

I don't know what can we further do to get the relation between $a,b,c$ and eliminate $x,y,z$

Secondly, it is obvious that

$(x+y+z)=(x^2+y^2+z^2) ;$

Then multiplying the equation by $a$ we can easily get $ax^2-ax$ and substituting that in the equation derived by subtracting 1st and 2nd equation but that doesn't help too

I am very confused about it....please give a solution to solve it ...

The answer given to the problem is:-

$(a+b+c)^3-4(a+b)(b+c)(c+a)+5abc=0 ;$

This is not a homework problem

Comment: In [M2](http://habanero.math.cornell.edu:3690/) `R=QQ[a,b,c]` `S=R[x,y,z]` `I=ideal(a*x+b*y+c*z,a*x^2+b*y^2+c*z^2,x*y+y*z+x*z)` `gens gb I` `toString oo -- matrix {{a*x+b*y+c*z, (a^2-b^2-a*c+b*c)*y*z+(-b*c+c^2)*z^2, (b-c)*x*z+(a-c)*y*z, b*y^2+(-a+b+c)*y*z+c*z^2, x*y+x*z+y*z, (a^3*c-a^2*b*c-a*b^2*c+b^3*c-a^2*c^2+3*a*b*c^2-b^2*c^2-a*c^3-b*c^3+c^4)*z^3, (a*c-c^2)*y*z^2+(a*c-b*c)*z^3, (b^2*c-b*c^2)*y*z^2+(a^2*c-a*b*c+b*c^2-c^3)*z^3, (a-c)*y^2*z+(a-b)*y*z^2}}`  `a^3-a^2*b-a*b^2+b^3-a^2*c+3*a*b*c-b^2*c-a*c^2-b*c^2+c^3 - ((a+b+c)^3-4*(a+b)*(b+c)*(c+a)+5*a*b*c) -- 0`.

Comment: Plz give a solution to the problem i unable to understand the link and comment you sent

Comment: The Gröbner basis in tex is $\langle ax+by+cz, (a^2-b^2-ac+bc)yz+(-bc+c^2)z^2, (b-c)xz+(a-c)yz, by^2+(-a+b+c)yz+cz^2, xy+xz+yz, c\cdot(a^3-a^2b-ab^2+b^3-a^2c+3abc-b^2c-ac^2-bc^2+c^3)z^3, (ac-c^2)yz^2+(ac-bc)z^3, (b^2c-bc^2)yz^2+(a^2c-abc+bc^2-c^3)z^3, (a-c)y^2z+(a-b)yz^2 \rangle.$ And it's posted as a comment, not an answer, since it's a computer algebra solution.

Comment: Ok thanks but please see if u can give a proper subjective solution with steps to obtain the answer

Comment: Comparing the first 2 equations, it is tempting to assume that a=x, b=y and c=z! Why not?

Comment: But 'tempting' doesnt make us solve this question

Comment: Try `c*((a+b+c)^3-4*(a+b)*(b+c)*(c+a)+5*a*b*c)*z^3//(gens I)` in M2, continuing the code above. It will produce the $f,g,h$ s.t. $$f\cdot (ax+by+cz)+g\cdot (ax^2+by^2+cz^2)+h\cdot (xy+yz+xz)$$ $$=c\cdot ((a+b+c)^3-4(a+b)(b+c)(c+a)+5abc)\cdot z^3.$$